# Intergrating Wordpress into another platform

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I'm currently using `Xsilva Lightspeed` as my e-commerce part of my site, and Wordpress as the CMS part of my site. I'd like to put Wordpress in my e-commerce site, so customers have access to their account, shopping cart, total, etc., while still using Wordpress to update any other content, such as my blog, from anywhere. I can't do that with Lightspeed.

My question is can two programs be used together, and can I use `Wordpress Codex` within the Lightspeed pages, or does the php language fight with each other? I put all of the Wordpress files within my e-commerce folder.

I've tried posting content from my Wordpress on Lightspeed using Wordpress codex, ie:

```
<?php
    $my_id = 17;
    $post_id_17 = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
    $title = $post_id_17['post_content'];
?>
```

I don't get an error, but nothing appears. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I dunno lightspeed, but I have integrated WP with other sites (magento, specifically)... fort instance, I need to use WP to manage a bunch of news posts, but the content needs to appear through out a magento store.

Usually what I do is to use the WP-JSON-API plugin to serve the content as a custom JSON call:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

And then I write whatever is necessary to call the info from the external WP install and pop it in the page.  This makes it pretty easy to just CURL to get the JSON, and then you decode that to an array to populate whatever content you need.

The other way, that would be in line with what you've tired, would be to include files from WP inside the lightspeed install... there very well may be some plugin somewhere that does this, but IMO, that is a more complicated route to take as you have to juggle two programs in the same space.